# I'm not sure why my def dice_game() is not being called when it is supposed to

Tags: python, function

So I have been trying to solve the problem, but I could not. When it asks for an NPC to pick and I pick the Lizzard man, the game that should call the function dice_game(), it does not want to be called. But I have no idea why. Below are the codes that I feel like is related to the problem that I am facing right now.

```
import random

#Dice Rolling Function
def dice_roll():
    dice_side = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    return random.choice(dice_side)

# Lizzard Man Mini Game: Dice Game
def dice_game():
    global points
    user_sum = 0
    npc_sum = 0
    while user_sum < 50 and npc_sum < 50:
        user_dice = dice_roll()
        npc_dice = dice_roll()
        print(f"You rolled: {user_dice}")
        print(f"Lizzard Man rolled: {npc_dice}")

        user_sum += user_dice
        npc_sum += npc_dice

        print(f"Your current sum is {user_sum}")
        print(f"Lizzard Man's current sum is {npc_sum}")

        if user_sum >= 50:
            print(f"Congratulations, {username}!! You have earned 10 points from winning.")
            points += 10
            confirmed_npc_function()
        elif npc_sum >= 50:
            print(f"{username}, sadly you have lost the game.")
            points += 5
            confirmed_npc_function()
        else: 
            print("Please type in 1 to roll the dice.")

#User Input Validation
def validate_input(prompt, valid_options):
    while True:
        user_input = input(prompt)
        if user_input in valid_options:
            return user_input
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid option.")

# Starting Point of Game: The Hidden Garden
def hidden_garden():
    global username
    print('\nWould you like to start a journey by opening the hidden pathway to the lost garden?')
    start_option = input("Enter 'Yes' or 'No': ")

    if start_option.lower() == "yes":
        username = input("What is your name?: ")
        if username.isalpha():
            print(f'\n{username.title()}, you are now the chosen warrior to save the village from the Dragon King.')
            spawn_area()
        else:
            print(f'\nSorry, please only type in alphabetical characters for your username.')
    else:
        print('Hoping to see you again next time!')

# NPC Confirmation Function
def confirmed_npc_function():
    global confirmed_npc
    confirmed_npc = ""
    while True:
        print("\nList of NPCs:")
        for npc in npc_lists:
            print(npc)
        conversation = input("\nNow, which NPC would you like to have a conversation with?: ").capitalize()
        if conversation in [npc.capitalize() for npc in npc_lists]:
            confirmed_npc = conversation
            break
        else:
            print("\nInvalid NPC selection. Please pick the correct NPC from the list.")
            continue
    
    npc_confirmation = input(f"\nAre you sure that you would want to talk to the {confirmed_npc}?\nType in 'Yes' or 'No': ")
        
    if npc_confirmation.lower() == "yes":
        if confirmed_npc == "Witch":
            witch_story()
        elif confirmed_npc == "Lizzard Man":
            dice_game()
        elif confirmed_npc == "Vampire":
            vampire_mg()
        elif confirmed_npc == "Phoenix":
            phoenix_mg()
        elif confirmed_npc == "Angel":
            angel_mg()
    else:
        print("\nInvalid NPC selection. Please pick the correct NPC from the list.")
        confirmed_npc_function()
```

I tried asking ChatGPT and tried to search online why it is not working, but I could not. I am expecting the def dice_game() to be called when user types in lizzard man, and then confirms to talk with the lizzard man

Comment: Just add `dice_game()` at the bottom.

Comment: line 30, in dice_game
    print(f"{username}, sadly you have lost the game.")
NameError: name 'username' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Change "Lizzard Man" to "Lizzard man" in your `elif` condition

Comment: oh.. Thank you so much. I feel very stupid for not catching that for a very long time. Once again, Thank you so much for helping!